# Exiting individual if elif statements

Tags: python

I have a program that generates a random question, to get a number and then display if the answer given is right or wrong.

for example:
if it asks to enter a positive number, you can enter a number and then it displays if the number is positive or not.

So i know that it gets the input correctly and can give the right answer, but it ends up giving multiple answers.

heres the code see for yourself:

```
import random

def RandomQuestions()
    questionsList=["Enter a number thats not prime:",
                   "Enter a number thats prime:",
                   "Enter a number thats odd:",
                   "Enter a number thats even:",
                   "Enter a number thats positive:",
                   "Enter a number thats negative:",]

    question = (random.choice(questionsList))

    print(question)

    getnum= int(input(""))

    if question [0]:
        if getnum <= 1:
            print("Correct", getnum, "is not prime.")
        elif getnum <=3:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is prime.")
        elif getnum%2==0 or getnum%3==0:
            print("Correct", getnum, "is not prime.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is prime.")

    if question [1]:
        if getnum <= 1:
            print("Incorrect", getnum, "is not prime.")
        elif getnum <=3:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is prime.")
        elif getnum%2==0 or getnum%3==0:
            print("Incorrect", getnum, "is not prime.")
        else:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is prime.")

    if question [2]:
        if (getnum%2)==0:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is even.")
        else:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is odd.")

    if question [3]:
        if (getnum%2)==0:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is even.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is odd.")

    if question [4]:
        if (getnum>0):
            print("Correct",getnum,"is positive.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is negative.")

    if question [5]:
        if (getnum>0):
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is positive.")
        else:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is negative.")import random

RandomQuestions()
```

So if your in the program it ends up giving answers for all the questions. How do i make it exit the if statement if it isnt related to the question list?

Comment: just use a return statement?

Comment: `question [0]` does not evaluate to something you can really use in a if-clause, you need to re-design that part

Comment: I hate to be slightly off topic, but that check whether a number is prime or not hurts me as a Maths Graduate. A better prime check would be `isPrime = lambda p : p >=2 and p != 4 and not any(map(lambda n : p % n == 0, range(2, (p + 1) // 2)))`

Comment: @JakeConkerton-Darby I thought the same but I assume he has some sort of upper limit he wants to check this on. His code would be correct for all numbers `< 25` (25 being non-prime but his code would call it prime).

If that's the case though, it might be sensible to check for that constraint early instead of implicitly assuming compliance.

Comment: @JakeConkerton-Darby yeah a couple of others told me my prime check was wrong as well, ill try your code, i actually got this prime check code from a wiki post as i remember. Thank you!

Comment: @SanushWattage I would note that my snippet is not efficient for large primes, it's a simple brute force check that is a bit quick and dirty but does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `question` contains a string. That means that `question[0]` contains the first char of the string, `question[1]` second char and so on. And that one char will be always evaluated as `True`.

The solution is to use `if question == questionsList[0]:` instead of `if question[0]:` and so on...

Comment: Yes! thank you so much! i didnt know that my chode would refer to the char of he string, your code works!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `if` statements always return true and code block inside of them always gets executed, try:

```
if question == questionsList[0]:
    ...
elif question == questionsList[1]:
    ...
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `question[0]` and `question[1]` you're accessing the character at that position in the text of the question (eg: `E` and then `n` and so forth) - a non empty string always equates to `True` so that's why all your `if`s are running.

A more elegant way of doing this is to pair up the questions and their validators when making a choice and then call the validator on the input after converting to an integer, eg:

```
from random import choice

def is_prime(number):
    # Write your prime checker here
    # Return True if prime or False if not
    pass

QUESTIONS = (
    # (text for question, callable to check if correct)
    ('not prime: ', lambda L: not is_prime(L)),
    ('prime: ', is_prime),
    ('odd: ', lambda L: L % 2 != 0),
    ('even: ', lambda L: L % 2 == 0),
    ('positive: ', lambda L: L > 0),
    ('negative: ', lambda L: L < 0)
)


question, answer_is_correct = choice(QUESTIONS)
number = int(input(question))
print('correct' if answer_is_correct(number) else 'wrong')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coode with some correction. This will help you in correlating the flow of if and elif in python.

```
import random

def RandomQuestions():
    questionsList=["Enter a number thats not prime:",
               "Enter a number thats prime:",
               "Enter a number thats odd:",
               "Enter a number thats even:",
               "Enter a number thats positive:",
               "Enter a number thats negative:",]

    question = (random.choice(questionsList))

    print(question)

    getnum= int(input(""))

    if question  == questionsList[0]:
        if getnum <= 1:
            print("Correct", getnum, "is not prime.")
        elif getnum <=3:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is prime.")
        elif getnum%2==0 or getnum%3==0:
            print("Correct", getnum, "is not prime.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is prime.")



    elif question == questionsList[1]:
        if getnum <= 1:
            print("Incorrect", getnum, "is not prime.")
        elif getnum <=3:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is prime.")
        elif getnum%2==0 or getnum%3==0:
            print("Incorrect", getnum, "is not prime.")
        else:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is prime.")


    elif question == questionsList[2]:
        if (getnum%2)==0:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is even.")
        else:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is odd.")


    elif question == questionsList[3]:
        if (getnum%2)==0:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is even.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is odd.")


    elif question == questionsList[4]:
        if (getnum>0):
            print("Correct",getnum,"is positive.")
        else:
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is negative.")


    elif question == questionsList[5]:
        if (getnum>0):
            print("Incorrect",getnum,"is positive.")
        else:
            print("Correct",getnum,"is negative.")

RandomQuestions()
```